# How put baseurl as a parametrs in selenium tests

Tags: python, linux, google-app-engine, selenium

I have 1 file with selenium tests, with baseURL in it. So now i need to find a way to launch this tests from console with URL as a parametr.

I have one local, developer and production server, so i want to run this tests without hardcode baseURL in it.

Is anyone one have some idea for this?
Waiting for your answers :3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create one `Environment` file any format would do (`.xml`, `.xlsx`, `.properties` `etc`).

Then you just mention environment specific details and parse the file. Its better if you use `.xml` format. In this way you can create node like configuration with parent being the `environment name.` In this way you can add any number of configuration for different servers.

Something like:-

**XML Format:-**

```
<environments>
    <environment id="local">
        <parameter>
            <name>host</name>
            <value>LocalURL</value>
        </parameter>
    </environment>
    <environment id="development">
        <parameter>
            <name>host</name>
            <value>DevelopmentURL</value>
        </parameter>
    </environment>
    <environment id="production">
        <parameter>
            <name>host</name>
            <value>ProductionURL</value>
        </parameter>
    </environment>
</environments>
```

**Properties File Format:-**

```
localUrl = http://local.com
developmentUrl = http://development.com
productionUrl = http://production.com
```

Any format you can use and write a code to parse it.